# Why is drawing to slick.Image.getGraphics() that slow?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

Im making a game using Java and the Slick2D library.
I have a button class with a render method that looks something like this:

```
public void render(Graphics g, int xOffset, int yOffset){
    int renderX = x+xOffset;
    int renderY = y+yOffset;

    if(hasFocus()){
        g.setColor(HIGHLIGHTEDBUTTONCOLOR);
    }else{
        g.setColor(BUTTONCOLOR);
    }
    g.fillRect(renderX, renderY, width, height);

    g.setColor(BUTTONTEXTCOLOR);
    g.drawString(text, renderX+(width/2) - (g.getFont().getWidth(text)/2), renderY+(height/2) - (g.getFont().getLineHeight()/2));    
}
```

This works great until I need to render only part of a button when the other part is outside the bounds of my scrollable container. I tried this:

```
Image temp = new Image(myButton.getWidth(), myButton.getHeight());
myButton.render(temp.getGraphics(),this.x, this.y);
temp.getSubImage(0, 0, int temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight()/2);
myGraphics.drawImage(temp, myButton.getX(), myButton.getY());
```

But this dropped my fps from 4000 to 10.

I tried making a blank image before hand and just copying it to draw to at render time but this didnt help.
I tried pre-rendering the image and it ran at 4000 fps again but whenever i changed the buttons text or whether or not it was highlighted I had to redraw the image which caused a freeze up.

How can I render only part of this button every frame without it being too slow.
also remember the portion of the button I need to render changes and if im scrolling it may change every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to set a world clip(area that can be rendered to) for the graphics of the game container.

```
g.setWorldClip(this.getX()+xOffset, this.getY()+yOffset, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

and then clear it after rendering the component

```
g.clearWorldClip();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never** ever draw to the internal graphics of an image in a frequently called and performance sensitive method such as render(...) or update(...).

First, this is why this

```
Image temp = new Image(myButton.getWidth(), myButton.getHeight());
myButton.render(temp.getGraphics(),this.x, this.y);
temp.getSubImage(0, 0, int temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight()/2);
myGraphics.drawImage(temp, myButton.getX(), myButton.getY());
```

is so slow:

1. You should avoid using the new operator in a frequently called method, as it is slow, especially when creating a new image context (where textures and internal buffers have to be created). If you really have to do something like this, try to implement some buffering, such as creating one image when initializing and reusing it in the method instead of re-creating.
2. The getGraphics() method **creates** a new instance of Graphics for the image, and this is called every frame in your code. As mentioned above, creating with the new operator should be avoided if possible in performance sensitive calls, and creating a new Graphics instance in a method like render(..) is probably the reason for the massive fps-drop in your application.

Additionally, controrary to a somewhat common belief, the getSubImage(..) method isn't actually that bad for performance and may be used in frequently called methods if necceassary, as it basically just clips the buffer information to the given size (but keeps a reference to the original image, so if you modify the sub-Image by e.g.: drawing on it the original will be modified as well!).

As a solution to your problem, you could clip the button manually and calculate the bounds for the button box yourself. In your case, you could do something like this (As you have not specified what kind of container you mean, I assume that it is some kind of GUI element  and it is a simple Rectangle, but this can easily be changed to fit your requirements):

```
//some pseudo-code as a help

if (buttonX within container bounds) buttonStartX = buttonX
else if (buttonX smaller than container bounds) buttonStartX = containerMinX

if (buttonX + buttonWidth within container bounds) buttonBoxWidth = buttonWidth
else if (buttonX + buttonWidth greater than container bounds) buttonBoxWidth = containerMaxX - buttonStartX

//... and so on... (yes the horizontal logic is not complete, but I dont want you to just copy this 
// without thinking but rather that you finish this yourself with the given approach :)
```